# Value is showing as 10 even though it subtracted score twice

Tags: python

```
dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
if (dice1 % 2) == 0:
    print("This number is even. Adding 10 to score.")
    player1score = player1score + 10
else:
    print("This number is odd. Subtracting 5 from score.")
    player1score = player1score - 5
if player1score < 0:
    print("Your score is too low. Reseting it to 0.")
    player1score = 0
dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
if (dice2 % 2) == 0:
    print("This number is even. Adding 10 to score.")
    player1score = player1score + 10
else:
    print("This number is odd. Subtracting 5 from score.")
    player1score = player1score + 10
if player1score < 0:
    print("Score too low, reseting to 0.")
    player1score = 0
print(player1score)
```

I ran this code and it came out as odd twice. The reset print worked but it never reset the variable back to 0 and at the end it showed the variable as 10 instead of 0 or a negative number. I'm confused

Help would be appreciated

Comment: This is a case of duplicating a piece of code when it is should have gone into a function that you call twice. That way if you have to make a change, it'll be only in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not doing what your comment says, on dice2 else-statement you are giving 10 points even though you say that you will subtract 5. Typo in comment or in code?

Comment: Oh, seems to have been a code typo on my end. That seems to have fixed it and it's now giving accurate variable outputs. Thanks for the help!

Comment: glad it fixed it :)